# Apply jquery function on content loaded via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

I load a panel (html) via Jquery (ajax), in the panel there is a loginform with a checkbox. I want to set the username in a cookie once the user clicks the checkbox (remember me). It is not working. Is there a solution?

```
$('#cookie').bind('change', function() {
       $.cookie("log_user", $("#log_user").val(), {expires: 14});
       $.cookie("log_pass", $("#log_pass").val(), {expires: 14});
});

  $("#gate").click(function () {
    var panel = $("#panel");
    if (!panel.data("loaded")) {
        $("#panel").load("/v3/ajax/panel.php");
        panel.data("loaded", true);

        var log_user = $.cookie('log_user');
        var log_pass = $.cookie('log_pass');
        // autofill the fields
        $('#log_user').attr("value", log_user);
        $('#log_pass').attr("value", log_pass);

    }
    panel.slideToggle("slow");
});




<form action="/members/login.php" method="post">
<label for="log_user">Username</label><input id="log_user" type="text" name="user" value="" maxlength="50"  /><br />
<label for="log_pass">Password  </label><input id="log_pass" type="password" name="pass" value=""  maxlength="50"  /><br />
<input id="cookie" type="checkbox" name="cookie" value="do" style="border: 0px;" /><label for="cookie"><small>Remember me</small></label><br />

<a title="Join Sionvalais" href="/members/register.php">register</a><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because you're using change() event rather than live() - as, assuming #cookie is only called into the page after your Ajax event, it doesn't exist at initial rendertime it can't bind the change event - checkout live() in the jquery API

http://api.jquery.com/live/

**UPDATE**

Following your comments I've put together the following mock up in JSFiddle, which seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/beardtwizzle/52JQX/2/

The only error I got during my tests were related to $.cookie - for which you need to include a plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt)

**UPDATE 2**

The problem definitely seems to be down to the cookie setting - try putting an `alert('hello world');` in-place of the cookie code and you should see that its getting there - that's assuming you're using live('change',function()... rather than bind.

BUT, thats not your real problem - your real problem is that this method of 'remember me' is INSECURE on so many levels.

1. You are attempting to store a poor visitors password in plain text - which is BAD
2. When you see a cookie on a user's machine you're going to just write out whatever is in there to the value attibute of your fields. By doing this you're assuming that the user has a genuine cookie from your site - and hasn't instead injected some of their own malicious code see (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

**MY ANSWER in light of the above**

My suggestion would be to drop this code ENTIRELY, then go away and read up on web security, then re-address it. If you go ahead and get this working you're going to hurt innocent users (and damage your reputation badly).

Comment: Hi, I changed the function but it is still not wortking (see my original post). Thanks for your help

Comment: Your updated code is using bind() rather than live() - can you also post a sample of the HTML being returned by your Ajax call. Cheers

Comment: Are you using a plugin for the $.cookie stuff - this isn't native to the JQuery api

Comment: If I go to the panel (page) I see the username and password. Once loaded in the website it is gone.. That is really strange

Comment: The problem you were originally experiencing seems entirely related to the Cookie plugin you're using. I would instead look up document.cookie (I'll try an post a working example in a bit). More to the point, I've only just realised you're proposing to store the password in a cookie - this is REALLY, REALLY bad - it means that any password that a user enters is stored in plain text. If anyone were to get hold of that users machine (either legitimately or via a XSS attack) they could see their password - which might well be the password they use for EVERYTHING

Comment: The password will not be stored eventually it was for testing only.

Comment: Ah ok, the writing out to value is still a vulnerability though. As I say, the code is all good (as far as I can see on my own machine). Its just the Cookie stuff - use document.cookie directly instead.

Comment: You mean like this:  $('#log_user').attr("value", $.cookie('log_user'));

Comment: Sorry no I mean don't use this plugin to handle your cookies - look at this http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp